# why is there a time displayed alongwith date?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying my hands on the pandas library and here's a code I have come up with to learn new things.

```py
#scratch.py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Hussain\Desktop\Returns.xlsx', header= 0,       encoding='utf', sep= '|')
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)


df.rename(columns={'Period Invested for': 'Investment Period', '₹10000    Invested on': 'Investment Date', 'Latest Value' : 'Current Value'}, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

```sh
$ python scratch.py
Investment Period   Investment Date         Current Value   ...
0                   2019-05-16 00:00:00     10427.4         ...
1                   2019-04-23 00:00:00     10127.5         ...
2                   2019-02-22 00:00:00     11029.6         ...
...
```

Example row from xlsx file:

```
3 Year,23-May-16,16633.59,66.34%,18.48%,13.52%,Jan-35
```

Can someone help me out in knowing why there's an inclusion of time in 24 hrs format in column 2 (investment date) while the excel i am working on has no mention of the time in it?

Comment: can you show the result of print?
Also: can you show at least one row from xlsx file (e.g. using csv representation)?

Comment: @imposeren https://imgur.com/PlBmQwd                       3 Year,23-May-16,16633.59,66.34%,18.48%,13.52%,Jan-35

Comment: That link is a 404, and I don't see any mention of time in that row.

Comment: @HussainAli, I've edited your question and added output example. You'd better include such info right away in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does recognize the column as 'datetime' format. You can read more on the subject here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

It is possible to obtain the dates from the datetime format, for example:

```py
df['Investment Date'] = df['Investment Date'].dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` prefers to use `datetime` for date columns instead of `date` and it's good because in many cases you might need to "mix" dates and datetimes in calculations, so it's easier to have datetimes everywhere, then to allow different behaviors for dates (e.g.: should "date" be interpreted as fixed point of like `00:00:00`, or should it be a range from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59.999999`..., some issues are also possible if you use time-zone aware datetimes and try to compare them with "dates" on DST switch dates).

But you can convert any column to any type you want:

```py
# A. convert value type as suggested in other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56300512/952437
df['Investment Date'] = df['Investment Date'].dt.date

# B. Only change output style:
import datetime
def dt_as_date(val):
    if isinstance(val, (pd.Timestamp, datetime.datetime)):
        return str(val.date())
    return val
df.style.format({'Investment Date': dt_as_date})
```

Comment: thank you for the insights. your proposed solution worked for me except that i had to write the code as follows:
    df['Investment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Investment Date'], errors='coerce')